# How to get names of parameters from POST request?

Tags: php, web, http-post

There a search service (PHP) which sends search query via POST. I would like to use that search engine in my app. The PHP service does not have a public API.

Is there a way to enter search query and to fetch a POST request to see the name of parameters? I would use then later to send a POST requests from my app and to catch POST responses.

This is an official search engine with governmental officials who do not reply to my requests to tell me the name of parameters. It's nothing illegal, app is free of charge, it's just that I can no longer wait for them as they will reply to me.

PS. I have access to Ubuntu shell and its admin tools.

**EDIT**

This is how the search form looks like in the source of the web page (seen via browser)

```
<form action="search.php" method="POST">
   <input type="text" name="search" size=20><br>
   SZ<input type="checkbox" checked name="sz">
   NZ<input type="checkbox" checked name="nz">
   <input type="submit" name="search_term" value="search" >
</form>
```

**EDIT 2**

Do not edit post as a guy suggested me the proper way to do this via linux command curl.

Comment: Could you send a curl request (from PHP or the linux shell) to the search engine? Then parse the repsonse?

Comment: Are you asking how to make POST requests on another website in PHP?

Comment: You just need to write some lines of PHP code! e.g you can use CURL extention of PHP to create & send POST requests & fetch result.

Comment: @BaileyMcAfee No. Nothing to do with a PHP. It's java app actually, but I need to know the names of POST parameters. Nothing to do with using PHP to make a POST request.

Comment: Can you show me how? Just to query http://site.com/search.php or what? I still do nor know which parameters names to use

Comment: Java coder here :). I can use curl from Linux shell but I need help as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried viewing the source on the search form to get the POST parameters? i.e. the name of the input box

**Edit**
take for example the php form on tizag site

```
<html><body>
<h4>Tizag Art Supply Order Form</h4>
<form action="process.php" method="post"> 
<select name="item"> 
<option>Paint</option>
<option>Brushes</option>
<option>Erasers</option>
</select>
Quantity: <input name="quantity" type="text" /> 
<input type="submit" />
</form>
</body></html>
```

the parameters are the input names i.e. quality and item

**Java code** (was using this for appengine)

```
HttpURLConnection connection = null;
String line = null;
BufferedReader rd = null;
String urlParameters = "search=search&submit=Submit";
serverAddress = new URL("http://www.search.com/search.php");
// set up out communications stuff
connection = null;
connection = (HttpURLConnection) serverAddress.openConnection();
// connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
connection.setRequestProperty("Referer", "");
connection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", ""); 
connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", "" + Integer.toString(urlParameters.getBytes().length));
connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Language", "en-US");
connection.setUseCaches(false);
connection.setDoInput(true);
connection.setDoOutput(true);
DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
wr.writeBytes(urlParameters);
wr.flush();
wr.close();
connection.connect();
if (connection.getResponseCode() == 404) {
    throw new ErrorException();
}
ArrayList<String> ud = new ArrayList<String>();
rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
    ud.add(line); // add response to arraylist
}
```

Comment: With the name of the input box you can make a post to the response page using java to get the response. i.e. making a post directly from your application to the search engine and interpenetrating its result

Comment: Hm... I will edit the question and post how search form looks in code

Comment: so you're saying i could make a POST request to URL http://site.com/search.php with parameter name pair values ("quality", "some term"), ("item","some item term")?

Comment: I will try asap and give you a BIG thanks if this works :))))

Comment: Unfortunately it does not work with me. I even get error trying to connect to your server url.

Comment: my server url is a dummy modify it to work with your code. main thing is to edit the urlParameters string with your target form. have you tried accessing the search form through get? some response page may evaluate both get and post.

Comment: yes I did but it didn't work. I will try to learn curl via linux command line and to fetch the whole request. i'll get back then

Comment: This works via curl shell command. Thanks for a GREAT advise. I'll be able now to find a way to make it work via Java code.

Comment: Another Q: What if a server script request a hidden id field (like I do with my scripts)? Is there a way to know which hidden field is needed by a remote script?

Comment: The hidden id field would also be tied to the form. try analyzing it and see if javascript is being used to add the hidden field.

Answer (score 0):

Whilst this is certainly something you could do with [curl in PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php), you should consider the possible consequences of scraping a government site to collect and reuse it's data.

Of course, I don't know how you will use the data, the importance of the data, the frequency of the requests or if you'll be using proxies. So might be nothing to worry about.

You want to know that parameters returned by a third party search engine. So you'd use curl to POST to the SE in question. Then parse the returned page and extract the information you're after.

**Edit:** Ok, so you're a Java guy. If you'd be more comfortable using the shell, read a few of the examples of PHP's "[exec](https://www.php.net/exec)" command. There's also the similar "[system](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.system.php)" and "[passthru](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.passthru.php)" you might want to look at.

Comment: Just to fetch some public documents, amendments to law and similar. Nothing illegal I said. And I am not afraid as this app is for community usage. Thanks anyway for caring

Comment: Yes, I am java coder :) and all I know is to use Linux shell curl command